# How do I execute scripts from Github code in Google Colab or jupyter ipython (ipynb) notebook?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

I would like to run the tensorflow training code from here

https://github.com/armancohan/long-summarization

The instructions say

> To run the code with the sample data unzip the files in the data
>   directory and simply execute the run script: ./run.sh. To train the
>   model with the entire dataset, first convert the jsonlines files to
>   binary using the the following script: scripts/json_to_bin.py and
>   modify the corresponding training data path in the run.sh script.

I was wondering how to import all the files and then run the scripts on colab?

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to convert the repo into a python package by putting code in folders, adding a setup.py, and **init**.py files.

I then tried running the code in 'run_summarization.py' right in colab but it gave me errors. It seems it was designed to be run via script so now I'm attempting to do that.

Here is the Google Colab notebook of that attempt.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MCUddFsa1va88myzSomIGROns9yLO-Z8